# Issue with capturing logs in custom Airflow operator based on DockerOperator using contextlib

Tags: python, airflow

Currently I am creating a custom airflow operator based on DockerOperator and for my specific usecase, I want to do some regex analysis of the logs and depending on the output I will return True or False.

I tried using contextlib, but it did not work

```
class DbtDockerBaseOperator(DockerOperator):
...
def execute():
   with io.StringIO() as buffer:
        with contextlib.redirect_stdout(buffer), contextlib.redirect_stderr(buffer):
            super().execute(context)
                
        output = buffer.getvalue()
       
        print("this is my output")
        print(output)
        print("end")
```

output is empty and all the logs are just printed into the terminal instead of being returned as a list of lines in the output.  This sounds more like a python problem, but all the solutions I have tried online did not work.

I know I can edit the source code and force the DockerOperator to return the list of logs, but not only this is kinda hacky, it would also be troublesome since I would be hindering my application in case there are updates in the docker operator.